# Trying to make a diaporama bullet list navigator with CSS

Tags: css, list, hover

this is my first post here. I am trying to make a horizontal empty bullet point list that will display a filled bullet point when the mouse passes over it.

The list is first defined in HTML using decimal code:

```
<ul class="btn-diaporama">
   <li>&#8226;</li> <!-- filled bullet point -->
   <li>&#9702;</li> <!-- unfilled bullet point -->
   <li>&#9702;</li>
   <li>&#9702;</li>
   <li>&#9702;</li>
</ul>
```

Then, I want the hover event in CSS to trigger a filled bullet point. Is it possible to switch the decimal value for each li when the mouse is passed over it. Specifically, this would change the value from &#9702 to &#8226 on a hovered over li element which would make the bullet appear full when the mouse passes over it. Possible?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the CSS `list-style` property.

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  /* unfilled bullet point */
  list-style: circle;
}

ul li:hover {
  /* filled bullet point */
  list-style: disc;
}
```

Codepen solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpgjJr

Comment: Thanks! It is so simple I almost feel ashamed to have worked with relative and absolute positioning. But my problem was that I wanted only bullets, no associated texts. I eventually found the following workaround:

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. Remember to mark correct answer when you're done, even if it's your own :)

Answer (score 0):

For a list with only bullets, no text:

HTML

```
<ul class="btn-diaporama">
   <li><span class="bullet">○</span></li>
   <li><span class="bullet">○</span></li>
   <li><span class="bullet">○</span></li>
   <li><span class="bullet">○</span></li>
   <li><span class="bullet">○</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    section ul li{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        color: #959595;
    }

    section ul li .bullet:hover:before {
        position: absolute;
        color: #636363;
        content: "●";
    }
```